# First half of the Double Arrow is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ in the Lower Limit Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

[What can we say about a locally compact Hausdorff space whose every open subset is sigma compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411735/what-can-we-say-about-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-space-whose-every-open-subset/411883?noredirect=1#comment8277300_411883)

My question is induced from these problem and from Henno Brandsma's answer.

I want to show in double arrow space the subspace $(0,1)\times\{1\}$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ in lower limit topology or the other name is Sorgenfrey line generated by $[a,b)$ type intervals.

Take double arrow space $[0,1]\times \{0,1\}$

My Attempt to show homeomorphism as follows:

Define $$\phi:(0,1)\times\{1\}\to (0,1)\\ (x,1)\mapsto x$$

from double arrow space to lower limit topology.

First of all it is clearly a bijection.

And continuous because take any open set in lower limit topology on $(0,1)$
as $[a,b)$

then $\phi^{-1}([a,b))=(a,\{0\}, b,\{1\})\cap (0,1)\times \{1\}$
it is open in subspace topology.

Is this way correct? And I cannot show $\phi $ is an open map because I cannot estimate general type of basic open sets in subspace of double arrow space.

Comment: I'm not sure where your formula for $\phi^{-1}([a,b))$ comes from. Isn't $\phi^{-1}([a,b))=[a,b)\times\{1\}$? I don't think that's an open set in $[0,1]\times\{1\}$ with the dictionary topology. In fact $(0,1)\times\{1\}$ is homeomorphic to the standard $(0,1)$, and so it cannot be homeomorphic to the lower limit topology on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @freakish No, in the dictionary order $(0,1) \times \{1\}$ is homeomorphic to the Sorgenfrey line, e.g. $[\frac12,1) \times \{1\}$ is relatively open as the trace of the lexicographic interval $\langle (\frac12,0),(1,1)\rangle$.

Comment: In the end we see that the Double arrow $[0,1]\times\{0,1\}$ consists of two copies of Sorgenfrey line, weirdly intertwined, and its min and max are isolated. So one often sees   $D= [0,1) \times \{1\} \cup (0,1] \times \{0\}$ being used (in the same order) to get a compact, connected, separable and perfectly normal ordered space that is not metrisable. I believe this is done in the paper by Aleksandrov and Urysohn where it was first defined. The Sorgenfrey line was defined separately later by Sorgenfrey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll call $(0,1) \times \{1\}$ in the subspace topology $\Bbb S_1$ for short.

A basic open subset of a point $(x,1)$ in $\Bbb S_1$ is of the form $\langle A,B\rangle \cap \Bbb S_1$, where $\langle A,B\rangle$ is a basic open interval of Double Arrow, where $A < (x,1) < B$ (the definition of the order topology, and the definition of subspace topology are applied here).

- If $A = (a,0)$, with $a \le x$, and $B=(b,0)$ or $B=(b,1)$ with $x < b$ we get that $\langle A,B\rangle \cap \Bbb S_1 = [a,b) \times \{1\}$
- If $A =(a,1)$ with $a < x$ and $B=(b,0)$ or $(b,1)$ with $x < b$ we get that
  $\langle A,B\rangle \cap \Bbb S_1 = (a,b) \times \{1\}$

In all cases the map $\phi: ((0,1), \mathcal{T}_s) \to \Bbb S_1, x \to (x,1)$
sends basic elements of $\mathcal{T}_s$ (the Sorgenfrey topology on $(0,1)$, which is homeomorphic to the full Sorgenfrey line by any order homeomorphism from $(0,1) $ to $\Bbb R$) to open subsets of $\Bbb S_1$, so $\phi$ is bijective (obvious) and open. As $\phi^{-1}[B]$ is also open for every basic open set of $\Bbb S_1$, as we saw, $\phi$ is also continous. We can check openness and continuity by base elements alone; this is standard.

It follows that $\Bbb S_1$ is homeomorphic to the Sorgenfrey line.